# how can i know my telegram-bot user pressed a button?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm developing a telegram bot with **python-telegram-bot**.

I send a message and a link (message body + inline keyboard button):

my question is how can I know if user clicked () on the link?
I want to do something if he clicked on link

```
btn = 'clicked'
link = InlineKeyboardButton(btn, url='www.google.ir', callback_data=btn)
keyboard = [[link]]
reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
bot.send_message(chat_id=uid, text='you should see this link to go next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a custom link which will do something that you want when the user opens it. After that user will be redirected to needed link.

For example:

```
Real link: https://example.com/category/article/1231
Your link: https://yourdomain.com/qwe213
```

You send your custom link and when the user opens this link, your script will do whatever you want then the user will be redirected to the real link.